# Angular service error in injectable

Tags: angular, typescript

I tried to follow angular tutorial, to make service in my project.

this is my auth service :

```
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import {HttpClient, HttpHeaders} from '@angular/common/http';
import {environment} from '../../environments/environment';

const httpOptions = {
    headers: new HttpHeaders({'Content-Type': 'application/json'})
};

@Injectable({providedIn: 'root'})
export class AuthService {

    private authUrl = environment.apiUrl + 'auth/';

    constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
    }

    login(username, password) {
        return this.http.post(this.authUrl + 'login', {username: username, password: password}, httpOptions);
    }

}
```

and in `app.module` I add `AuthService` in `providers`.

In `app.module` also I import :

```
import {HttpClientModule} from '@angular/common/http';
```

This is the error I got :

```
ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: undefined is not a function
TypeError: undefined is not a function
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at webpackAsyncContext (eval at ./src/$$_lazy_route_resource lazy recursive (main.bundle.js:20), <anonymous>:302:34)
    at SystemJsNgModuleLoader.loadAndCompile (core.js:6558)
    at SystemJsNgModuleLoader.load (core.js:6542)
    at RouterConfigLoader.loadModuleFactory (router.js:4543)
    at RouterConfigLoader.load (router.js:4523)
    at MergeMapSubscriber.eval [as project] (router.js:2015)
    at MergeMapSubscriber._tryNext (mergeMap.js:128)
    at MergeMapSubscriber._next (mergeMap.js:118)
    at MergeMapSubscriber.Subscriber.next (Subscriber.js:92)
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at webpackAsyncContext (eval at ./src/$$_lazy_route_resource lazy recursive (main.bundle.js:20), <anonymous>:302:34)
    at SystemJsNgModuleLoader.loadAndCompile (core.js:6558)
    at SystemJsNgModuleLoader.load (core.js:6542)
    at RouterConfigLoader.loadModuleFactory (router.js:4543)
    at RouterConfigLoader.load (router.js:4523)
    at MergeMapSubscriber.eval [as project] (router.js:2015)
    at MergeMapSubscriber._tryNext (mergeMap.js:128)
    at MergeMapSubscriber._next (mergeMap.js:118)
    at MergeMapSubscriber.Subscriber.next (Subscriber.js:92)
    at resolvePromise (zone.js:809)
    at resolvePromise (zone.js:775)
    at eval (zone.js:858)
    at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:421)
    at Object.onInvokeTask (core.js:4740)
    at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:420)
    at Zone.runTask (zone.js:188)
    at drainMicroTaskQueue (zone.js:595)
```

I use a premium template that I bought from internet, its use lazy route.

Where I am wrong and how to solve this case?
When I add new service I got same errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have used `providedIn: 'root'` - you don't need to add it into the providers. Your service will be as a *singleton* for whole application. Remove service from the providers.

`providedIn` lets us to not add it into the providers. We can just specify to which module we want it to provide.

Comment: thanks dude, and also I must upgrade angular version to 6